# Ubuntu/Grub2: Crypted grub password doesn't work, what could be the reason?

Tags: security, grub2

I've used the command `grub-mkpasswd-pbkdf2` in order to encrypt my password, then I took the hashed password and placed it in my Ubuntu 14.04 `/etc/grub.d/00_header`:

```
cat << EOF
set superusers="itaig"
password itaig grub.pbkdf2.sha512.10000.blah.blah
set superusers="lel"
password lel P@ssw0rd
export superusers
EOF
```

And at the end I ran update-grub2 to update grub. After reboot, I get a password prompt, when I use the user with the encrypted password I get an error and I'm unable to log into grub to continue the boot process. When I use the user with the cleartext password I am able to log into grub and continue the boot process successfully. What could be the cause for this problem? 
Here's a screen shot of the relevant section of `/etc/grub.d/00_header`:
[image]

The entry for user "lel" which has an unencrypted password works like a charm.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you need to change your crypted password line

the entry should be

```
password_pbkdf2 itaig grub.pbkdf2.sha512.10000.bla.bla
```

see

[Ubuntu Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Passwords)

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I'm not sure how I fixed it, but I configured `/etc/grub.d/01_users` file, and it works! See the sample below :

```
#!/bin/sh -e
cat << EOF
set superusers="root"
password_pbkdf2 root grub.pbkdf2.sha512......
EOF
```

I configured it on Centos 7

Answer (score 0):

I had found problem. I created a file without execute permission. I changed it to 755 and it works.

To ensure that worked, check de boot file config  `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` after update. 
You'll found configs similar that!

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/11_users ###
set superusers="root"
password_pbkdf2 root grub.pbkdf2.sha512.10000....
### END /etc/grub.d/11_users ###
```